# How do I defeat Orthros in Glory of Heracles (DS)?

Tags: glory-of-heracles

The Nintendo DS title "[Glory of Heracles](http://gloryofheracles.com/)" is a turn based RPG.

Orthros is a boss character in a mine.  The tricky thing about defeating him seems to be that when you think you've got him beat, he doubles or triples. I've killed him seventeen times, or more, but each time I do a final attack that has enough HP damage to finally kill him, he survives it, and replicates.  I'm randomly experimenting with the magic I have available, and physical attacks ,and it seems that the "elemental ether scores" at the top of the screen are the key to the puzzle, and if one can find attacks that show an up-arrow icon then they are 'more effective'...  The party has three characters, level 9 at the beginning of the battle, in my case.  This may also be part of the problem. Perhaps you need to grind longer and arrive at this quest with level 10 and more magic?

Comment: Found a video showing how to defeat it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmVd-a8ROPA

Comment: If you've got something that solved your problem, you can always post it as an answer and accept it.  That way, anybody else who views the question can see what worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a video linked as a comment above, but it doesn't show exactly how to defeat it.

1. It seems lightning and ice are what you should focus on attacking Orthros with, rather than Fire or Earth powers.
2. One of your party members has area-effect spells that can damage an entire row. With a little luck, multiple copies of orthros will line up on a single row for you.  It seems to help to back-up (retreat) and this seems to make Orthros come after you and then you can use the row-effect spells.